# Enable a specific define and set output path when compiling C++Builder 2010 project with msbuild

Tags: msbuild, c++builder, c++builder-2010

How do you, using *msbuild* from cmd build a *C++ Builder 2010* project and specify that you want the created exe to end up in **"../FooBar"** and that the *define* **"FOO"** should be set while compiling? I don't want it to delete any of the other defines already defined in the .cbproj file.

I have tried all kinds of Properties in my msbuild script but nothing seems to work. Is C++ Builder 2010 using a version of msbuild that is to old to support this?

To clarify, this is all done in a *msbuild script* that uses the `<msbuild />` task tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issues by instead creating a new build configuration and running that config from the build script.